# How to combine an introduction video made in blender to a UPBGE game

Tags: animation, video

I made an animation using blender 2.92. I also created a game using UPBGE 0.30. I am trying to combine both but not sure how. Is there a way to maybe use the logic brick editor to end the introduction and start the game. I have both in the same file in different scene's.

Answer (score 0):

One way maybe could be:

Make an empty and parent all objects to that empty.

With the delay actuator you could later ...

[image]

change the visibility of that empty (with children checked)

[image]

Animation can be played with the Action Actuator:
[image]